# Make Current move into last

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, move

Can I know how to move the value of current to last after I update it? 
I want to move **current table** to **last** after I update record with Id 1 ([Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WyB1F.png))

For example, if the value in column **Current** is **15** and I update it to **14** the value in column **Last** must be set to **15**

```
public function updateOthers(Request $request, $id)
{
    $other = other::find($id);


    $other->otherInitialRequirementCountLast=$other->otherInitialRequirementCount;
    $other->otherInitialSolutionCountLast=$other->otherInitialSolutionCount;
    $other->otherFeedbackCountLast=$other->otherFeedbackCount;
    $other->otherSolutionDesignCountLast=$other->otherSolutionDesignCount;
    $other->otherSolutionDevelopmentCountLast=$other->otherSolutionDevelopmentCount;
    $other->otherPOCCountLast=$other->otherPOCCount;
    $other->otherProposalReadyCountLast=$other->otherProposalReadyCount;

    $other->projectName=$request->input('projectName');
    $other->segment=$request->input('segment');
    $other->description=$request->input('description');
    $other->customer=$request->input('customer');
    $other->lastAction=$request->input('lastAction');
    $other->nextAction=$request->input('nextAction');
    $other->status=$request->input('status');
    $other->information=$request->input('information');
    $other->currentProgress=$request->input('currentProgress');
    $other->startProject=$request->input('startProject');
    $other->finishProject=$request->input('finishProject');        

    $other->otherInitialRequirementCount=$other->where('currentProgress','Like','Initial Requirement')->count();
    $other->otherInitialSolutionCount=$other->where('currentProgress','Like','Initial Solution')->count();
    $other->otherFeedbackCount=$other->where('currentProgress','Like','Menunggu Feedback & Gathering Req')->count();
    $other->otherSolutionDesignCount=$other->where('currentProgress','Like','Solution Design')->count();
    $other->otherSolutionDevelopmentCount=$other->where('currentProgress','Like','Solution Development')->count();
    $other->otherPOCCount=$other->where('currentProgress','Like','POC')->count();
    $other->otherProposalReadyCount=$other->where('currentProgress','Like','Proposal Ready')->count();


    $other->update();

  return redirect::to('/tableOthers');
}
```

Please help me to solve this question.